# how to activate and deactivate user account with mongobd using node js

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

api for to activate and deactivate user account using node js and mongodb.I'm able to deactivate user account from the view without removing the data from the database ,simply block the user from login. Rather than using delete api i want to use this deactivate api(it's preferable for account)

Answer (score 1):

The common way to soft delete or deactivate a user is using `isDeleted` property. When it set to `true` mean this user is deleted (soft delete) and when it is `isDelete = {$ne: true}`, meaning it didn't delete.

In all of your documents (records), you can use this policy.

Comment: I was looking for this function and I came here today and I found your reply lemme test if It works I am giving you a tick